# How to access buttons in DataGrid cells (column/row) programmatically in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that has (editable) columns bound to items of a `ObservableCollection`.
In addition each row has a "Save" button defined in XAML as

```
<DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ...
    <DataGridTemplateColumn >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Save" Click="OnSave"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Whether or not a button of a row is enabled depends on item properties in connection with authorization rules implemented in c#.

In addition the `Button Content` should change depending on the language that the user selects (which the user can do at any time).

So I have the need to somehow get access to the button objects in c# code but haven't found a way to do this so far.

Comment: Bind Content to a property of the view model item class. And instead of a Click event handler, bind its Command property to an ICommand property in the item class. ICommand has a CanExexute method that disables the command target when it returns false.

Comment: @Clemens Bind Content to a property of the view model item class ...The item class is in the business object domian which I can not change (but I could extend it ...). So far I have not used ICommand, could you provide or link ton an example ?

Comment: There is plenty of information available on the internet. Just search for ICommand and its common implementations RelayCommand and DelegateCommand.

Comment: For the Content Binding, you may as well bind to a property in the parent view model, like `Content="{Binding DataContext.SomeProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"`

Comment: @Clemens I bound the button content to a property of my UserControl derived class and together with the `INotifyPropertyChanged`implementation and handling the content is now changed when the user changes the language. Thank you for the tipp! I will now digg deeper into ICommand ...